# Create A Mixin With and Without Border

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm trying to create a Mixin that takes one out of two variables and creates a filled button, or an outlined button depending on the variable passed.

```
@include button-style($color: red);

// would result in
background-color: transparent;
color: red;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red;

@include button-style($bg: red);

// would result in
background-color: red;
color: white;
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm going crazy over here trying to work out the simplest way to achieve this. Here's what I've got so far.

```
@mixin button-style($bg: transparent, $color: white) {
  background-color: $bg;
  color: $color;
  @if $color == 'white' {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px $color;
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me. I've set up an [working example over here](http://sassmeister.com/gist/bc403c4880cf6a07c52e). The only drawback is I'm having to tie `transparent` to a variable like so:

```
$transparent: transparent;

@mixin button-style($bg: $transparent, $color: white) {
  background-color: $bg;
  color: $color;
  @if $bg == $transparent {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px $color;
  }
}

.button-pri {
  @include button-style($bg: red);
}

.button-sec {
  @include button-style($color: red);
}
```

If possible I would like to cut that variable out of the equation and go straight for `if $bg == 'transparent { ...`, but that `if` statement doesn't seem to work with a string.

**Update**

Thanks to @KreaTief, apparently I don't need to use a variable. Updated answer below:

```
@mixin button-style($bg: transparent, $color: white) {
  background-color: $bg;
  color: $color;
  @if $bg == transparent {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px $color;
  }
}

.button-pri {
  @include button-style($bg: red);
}

.button-sec {
  @include button-style($color: red);
}
```

Comment: actually if works if you write the if statement as @if $bg == transparent --> http://sassmeister.com/gist/849233dd8093680c3f46

Comment: Thanks duder! Updated answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra argument and perform a check against that.

```
@mixin button-style($bg: transparent, $color: white, $border: true) {
  background-color: $bg;
  color: $color;
  @if $border {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px $color;
  }
}

.foo {
  @include button-style;
}

.bar {
  @include button-style($border: false);
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px white;
}

.bar {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
}
```

Alternately, you can use nulls:

```
@mixin button-style($bg: transparent, $color: white, $border: inset 0 0 0 1px $color) {
  background-color: $bg;
  color: $color;
  box-shadow: $border;
}

.foo {
  @include button-style;
}

.bar {
  @include button-style($border: null);
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to not have an extra argument in the `@include`, if that's possible? Maybe it's not possible...

Comment: It's either add the extra argument or tie it to one of the other arguments in such a way that either the background or color must be set in order to get your border.  There is a 3rd option, but it is significantly more verbose.

Comment: Can Mixin if/else statements take a string? For example, `@if $color == 'white'`??

Comment: Why are you asking me that instead of testing for yourself?  You could have saved yourself some time.

Comment: So I've got this working over here: http://sassmeister.com/gist/f1079496e74af06ff5f1 Only drawback is I'm having to use a variable called `$null`. I'd rather not use the variable if possible and refer to it like so: `@if $bg == 'null'`... Is this possible?